# Condition for Button

Tags: android

I want to add a condition for a ShowSolution button. When you press the submit button which is my AnswerCheck Method, this is only when you will able be press the Show Solution button. Is there any way to do this? Would Appreciate the help, Thanks.

```
public void AnswerCheck2(View view) {

        EditText num2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answertext2);
        int val2 = Integer.parseInt(num2.getText().toString());


        area = number3 * number3;

        if (val2 == area) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "The answer is correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "The answer is incorrect ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    public void ShowSolution2(View view){
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.solution2)).setText
                ("The Solution is "+number3 + " * " +number3);

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2)).setText("The answer is "+area);
    }


}
```

Comment: Please explain your question clearly.

Comment: The person has to input their answer in an EditText, Then they will press submit to see if their answer is correct, if their answer is incorrect, there is a Show Solution button which allows them to see the solution and answer, they can press to see the solution without even inputting an answer that is not what i want to happen. How do i restrict the person from pressing the ShowSolution button before they enter the answer?

Comment: You can disable the ShowSolution button at first and inside else block of AnswerCheck2 method enable it.

Comment: Initialize your button say"solutionButton"  and solutionButton.setEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, there are multiple ways to enable/display a button depending on a condition, such as:

- `button.setEnabled(true)`
- `button.setVisibility(VISIBLE)`

where `button` is the button you got from calling `findViewById(id)`.

Of course this would also mean that your button was disabled or hidden previously, but it's difficult to offer guidance without further explanation.

Comment: how do you implement the button.setEnabled(true)  function?

Comment: You can disable your button in the layout's XML with `android:enabled=false`, and then on your true condition just call `findViewById(R.id.**your_button_id**).setEnabled(true)`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked,i would like a pop up box to appear for the Submit Button saying "Enter answer before submitting" if the person tries submitting before they enter in the answer in the EditText

Comment: Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you first want user to submit their answer and then only after submitting their answer,  want to show solution button.

Then in that case use this:-

Initially In oncreate method :- 
solutionbutton.setvisibility(false)

Then in answercheck2:-
Solutionbutton.setvisibility.setvisibility(true)
num2.setfocusable(false)

This way you can also control user from changing there answer later